# AngularJS Access to JSON Nested Object Fails

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a JSON Object graph that looks like this (note there is only 1 array in the object called `lineItems`:

```
{
  "salesOrderUid": 52,
  "orderNumber": "1428002206349",
  "billToCity": "Golden",
  "billToFirstName": "Duke",
  "billToLastName": "Developer",
  "shipToStreetNumber": "12345",
  "shipToUnitNumber": null,
  "shipToZipCode": 80401,
  "promoCode": "Test",
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "salesOrderLineUid": 59,
      "salesOrderUid": 52,
      "extendedPrice": 50,
      "itemQuantity": 10,
      "itemPrice": 5,
      "catalogItem": {
        "catalogItemUid": 1,
        "itemPrice": 5,
        "catalog": {
          "catalogUid": 1,
          "validFrom": 1420095600000,
          "validThrough": 1435644000000
        },
        "item": {
          "itemUid": 1,
          "productCategoryUid": 1,
          "productDescription": "Product used for testing",
          "productName": "Test"
        }
      },
      "shipmentUid": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I iterate over `lineItems` like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="salesOrderLineItem in salesOrder.lineItems">
  <td>{{salesOrderLineItem.catalogItem.catalog.productName}}</td>
  <td>{{salesOrderLineItem.itemQuantity}}</td>
  <td>{{salesOrderLineItem.itemPrice | currency}}</td>
  <td>{{salesOrderLineItem.extendedPrice | currency}}</td>
</tr>
```

The "first level" properties are displayed just fine. (`itemQuantity`, `itemPrice` and `extendedPrice`) But nothing gets displayed for the nested property called `catalogItem.catalog.productName`.

The JSON object reflected above came directly out of the Developer Tools console so it's clear that the contents are there. And the catalogItem property is not an array so I should be able to chain object property references, shouldn't I?

I've seen many questions posted related to accessing nested JSON but they seem to all have nested arrays in the JSON...which is not the case here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`catalog` does not contain a field called `productName`. Did you mean to use `item` instead of `catalog`?

Comment: Yes, I did intend to use "item" instead of "catalogItem"...thought I had tried that without success. Apologies for submitting such a "simple" question. As always, appreciate the responses!

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that 'productName' is nested under 'item', not 'catalog'.

Change the line to be

```
<td>{{salesOrderLineItem.catalogItem.item.productName}}</td>
```

And that should be what you are looking for?